# How can I set up reviewdog for android and jetpack compose?

Tags: android, github-actions, detekt, ktlint

```
name: reviewdog
on: [ pull_request ]

jobs:
    ktlint:
        name: Ktlint Check Code Quality
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            -   name: Clone repo
                uses: actions/checkout@main
                with:
                    fetch-depth: 1

            -   name: ktlint
                uses: ScaCap/action-ktlint@master
                with:
                    github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
                    reporter: github-pr-review
                    android: true
                    fail_on_error: true
                    level: warning

    detekt:
        name: Check Code Quality
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            -   name: Clone repo
                uses: actions/checkout@v2
                with:
                    fetch-depth: 1
                    ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

            -   name: detekt
                uses: alaegin/Detekt-Action@v1.22.0
                with:
                    github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
                    detekt_config: detekt-config.yml # Change config path
```

And the result

```
182 kotlin files were analyzed.
Complexity Report:
    - 11,105 lines of code (loc)
    - 9,579 source lines of code (sloc)
    - 6,240 logical lines of code (lloc)
    - 223 comment lines of code (cloc)
    - 669 cyclomatic complexity (mcc)
    - 247 cognitive complexity
    - 0 number of total code smells
    - 2% comment source ratio
    - 107 mcc per 1,000 lloc
    - 0 code smells per 1,000 lloc

Project Statistics:
    - number of properties: 794
    - number of functions: 414
    - number of classes: 156
    - number of packages: 54
    - number of kt files: 182
```

I can't be 0 code smell. Is there any problem?

And I am curious about detekt-config.yml. Is it generated by reviewdog or is it local file that I created?